# What does “tapped up” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english

And for many loyal Labour Party supporters this weekend their ‘Whammy Burger’ moment arose at around 11am on Sunday when they were **tapped up** for £20 via an email which addressed them: Dear Firstname. It’s a small thing, but then it’s a whopping thing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context it is a slang phrase meaning asking for money.

Usually, a cheeky request for a comparatively small amount of money, the donation of which gives no obvious benefit to the donor.

(Entry 2.1 from [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tap) OED definition)

It is British slang, I'm not sure if it is used in other parts of the world.

Comment: In the US, we usually say *tapped* without the "up", in the experience of this NYC native.  To tap someone is usually to select them for something (as in *[the governor tapped him for a seat on the court](https://books.google.com/books?id=oUFClQ0S_sYC&lpg=PA51&dq=%22tapped%20him%20for%22&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q=%22tapped%20him%20for%22&f=false)*) but we do sometimes use it for requests, like ["The jerk apparently felt he was above being tapped for cash..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=MeBCNkVYWCkC&lpg=PA64&dq=%22tapped%20him%20for%22&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q=%22tapped%20him%20for%22&f=false))